# Using an MVC Route for an old page.aspx?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

We are re-writing an old asp.net site into MVC4.

There are many links to our site that look like this (that we don't control but must support):

```
 www.some.com/page.aspx?id=5
```

Is there a way to get a request for **/page.aspx?id=5** into a Route so that we can handle the request, pass it to a controller/action and then handle it from there?

Comment: If you don't need to use the old route in the app, I prefer to use IIS to rewrite the old url to the new.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the RouteConfig, add a route (before default route):

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "DefaultAspx",
                    url: "page.aspx",
                    defaults: new { controller = "MyAspxPage", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

In the controller catch the page id:

(MyAspxPageController)

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    // Do whatever needed
    //return View();
}
```

Comment: Good info. I'd like to add, for anyone else who might be thinking of leaving the original .aspx file in place, you'll need to either rename it or following these [instructions](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2013/08/29/asp-net-mvc-routing-intercepting-file-requests-like-index-html-and-what-it-teaches-about-how-routing-works.aspx) to route a file/resource that exists.

Answer (score 0):

Check out, you might also introduce "areas" to your app - it's helpful if your project is big enough. And if you use them, they will reflect on your routes.